# Warning from Compass when using Singularitygs

Tags: compass-sass, singularitygs

With
     - Sass 3.3.0 rc2 
     - Compass-core 1.0.0.alpha16
     - Compass 1.0.0.alpha17
     - Singularitygs 1.1.2

I am getting a warning message
 - "Warning: Compass has changed how browser support is configured..."
when trying to compile.

```
singularitygs/helpers/_box-sizing.scss is calling 
compass/css3/_deprecated-support.scss which in turn calls
compass/_support.scss (line 379) which contains the warning message.
```

I tried to search for change log but can't seem to find one.  How do I resolve this warning?

Answer (score 0):

Singularity 1.1.x is not compatible with with Sass 3.3.x or Compass 1.1.x, although Singularity 1.2.x (being worked on now) will be. Please refer to the [Singularity installation requirements](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Installation#requirements) that explain the versions of Sass and Compass that Singularity is compatible with.

Comment: Thank you for your work.  It looks like the new version is getting closer.   I'll wait for the new version.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the issue [here](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/pull/157) but Singularity currently does not yet support Sass 3.3.x nor Compass 1.x, though it is planned for version 1.2

Comment: My mistake.  I ran 'gem update' and that pushed the Compass to the latest version.